# How do I determine if the series $ e^{-2n} $ converges or diverges? (From $ 0\to \infty $)

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I need homework help, I am mostly getting hung up on the integral. The question is:

> Determine if the series
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-2n}}$$
>   converges or diverges.

Again, it isn't the concept I don't understand, it is the integral of e. Anything helps, thank you!

Here's what I have thus far:

$$\int_1^\infty e^{-2x}dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}\left[-\frac{e^{-2x}}{2}\right]_1^b=\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(-\frac{e^{-2b}}{2}\right)-\left(-\frac{e^{-2}}{2}\right)$$

Comment: What are the limits of your sum?

Comment: What integral are you having trouble with? This is a series, not an integral... and it's a geometric series at that.

Comment: $\int{e^{f(x)}dx}=\frac{1}{f'(x)}e^{f(x)}+C$

Comment: Sorry, the section we are currently on is "Integral Test", so I thought I needed to integrate it to solve it. The limits are n=1 to infinity, I don't know how to format equation and advanced symbols on here :( So I have tried integrating it and tried using integration by parts so far and I'm stuck.

Comment: That's not right, @RhysHughes. There is no general form for the antiderivative of $e^{f(x)}$.

Comment: In this case it certainly holds

Comment: @RhysHughes Yes, of course it holds if your function $f$ is a **very** particular function. But it fails to hold in general and is a common false belief among students; your comment is misleading at best.

Comment: @T.Bongers can you give a counter-example?

Comment: @RhysHughes Any non-linear function gives a counterexample... as do constant functions. So take $f(x) = 1$ or $f(x) = x^2$.......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

This is a geometric sum, think of when does geometric sum converges? what is the common ratio here?

Edit:

You actually almost did it.

$$\lim_{b \to \infty} \left(-\frac{e^{-2b}}{2} \right)-\left(-\frac{e^{-2}}{2} \right)=\frac{e^{-2}}{2}<\infty, $$

Hence it converges.

Comment: I know how to do geometric sums, and it is in the correct format to use the equation. I know that e^n goes to infinity.

Comment: not sure how does $e^n$ helps you directly. What is the integral that you are facing difficulty with? have you tried substitution?

Comment: I need help with integration. I am not very good with integration by parts or substitution and my professor does not help me at all.

Comment: can you write down the integral that you want to integrate for me?

Comment: It is e^(-2n), the original post.

Comment: You want to integrate $\int_0^\infty e^{-2x} \, dx$, let $y=-2x$, try to do a substitution.

Comment: plus 1 for patiently leading op to answer rather than giving it.

Answer (score 1):

By the integral test, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) < \infty$  iff $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx < \infty$. Can you test it?

**UPDATE**

Use $u = -2x$ then $du = -2dx$ and
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-2x} dx
 = \int_{u=0}^{u=-\infty} e^u \frac{du}{-2}
 = \frac{1}{-2} \int_0^{-\infty}e^u du.
$$
Can you finish this now?

Comment: I need help taking the integral of this, though. Can I have help with that? I really struggled with integration of logarithms.

Comment: @StephanieGreen please see the update, can you do it now/?

Comment: did you change the bounds because the sign changed?

Comment: @StephanieGreen no, because we changed variables. The original bounds are $x=0$ and $x=\infty$ and you get $u=-2x = -2\cdot 0 = 0$ for the first one and $u = -2x = -\infty$ for the second one.

Answer (score 1):

See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

So you need to integrate this:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}{e^{-2n}}dn$$$$\rightarrow \bigg[-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2n}\bigg]^{\infty}_{1}$$
$$\rightarrow-\frac{1}{2e^{2\infty}}-\frac{1}{2e^2}$$

To say $2e^{2\infty}$ isnt technically correct, but appreciate that $\frac{1}{2e^L}\rightarrow0$ as $L\to \infty $, hence the result is convergence to $\frac{1}{2e^2}$

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. That term on the right is constant, so forget about it. You have $\lim_{b\to\infty} \frac{-e^{-2b}}{2} = -\frac12\lim_{b\to\infty}e^{-2b}$. What happens if you take $e$ to the power of a large negative number? (You can think of $e^{-2b}$ as $\frac1{e^{2b}}$ instead if that helps.)

Comment: it gets closer to zero, right?

Comment: @StephanieGreen Yup!

Answer (score 0):

Your series is a geometric series, so you can just look up the partial sums:

$$\sum_{n=0}^N e^{-2n}=\frac{1-e^{-2(N+1)}}{1-e^{-2}}\xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} \frac 1{1-e^{-2}}.$$

So your series converges (and you even have the value it converges to !).

Comment: I totally agree with that and understand that, but I am confused because this section is "Integral Test", so why don't I take the integral of this?